# CallContext - What are the recommendations for using this going forwards?

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, async-ctp, .net-4.5

Does anyone know if there's any planned support in upcoming versions of .NET for storing objects in the ambient execution context? There's a definite need for it, as highlighted in the following pages:

Limitations of CallContext: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/276325/provide-better-context-support-to-async-operations

Implicit vs Explicit Context: http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/11/08/the-importance-of-context-and-a-question-of-explicitness.aspx

The types of object which could be added to ambient execution context are:

- Those which are not suitable for DI. I.e. extrinsic dependencies which should be defined by the call-site, but cross-cut the application-domain in a way which makes them impractical to be passed as method arguments. Examples: CancellationToken, IProgress, Transactions, SynchronizationContext, SecurityContext. *(In fact, ExecutionContext has been hardcoded to pass the latter 2 around... any good reason why an open collection cannot be exposed for custom code?)*
- Those which are used by generic code emitted into method bodies... code which has no knowledge about the explicit dependencies available to it as arguments on the housing method, or properties of its declaring type. Consider PostSharp Aspects in the AOP world.

Would be great to hear people's thoughts on this one :)

**EDIT:**
Have posted question here too: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/async/thread/ea21ca57-5340-439c-8ee9-f0185b5787a1

Comment: The MS Async team doesn't monitor SO, but they are responsive on the [official forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/async/threads). This would be a great question to ask there.

Comment: Actually, they do read SO and frequently respond to questions. The signal-to-noise ration of SO is much, much higher than the MSDN forums. And of course, Jon Skeet seems to answer SO questions far more often than he answers in the forums

Comment: I see good participation from MS's compiler/VS teams, so questions re how `async` interacts with the compiler have good coverage (the "internal" part of async). The rest of the Async CTP isn't covered as well on SO by MS (the "external" part of async) - I've observed much better responses for this side of things on the forums (particularly by Stephen Toub).